# Non-EU Student in Germany staying in Schengen area after their studies have ended

Tags: schengen

I am a Brazilian student in Germany. Before coming to Germany, I spent 6 weeks traveling in Europe and figuring out some stuff for the University. That was back in mid-February. My classes started in April and will last until end of September. I would like to travel within Europe after my classes end. AFAIK, that's when my residency permit will no longer be valid. Am I eligible for Schengen's 90 days after my studies since I arrived in mid-February? By the time my residency permit has to be returned to the German authorities it will have been over 180 days since I first stepped in the Schengend area.